# How to check number of emoticons in textbox in php?

Tags: php, maxlength, emoticons

I am relieving a text from android as post data this may be alphabet or emoticons, how can check that if emoticons then should not be greater than 25 in server side in php.

Please help me 
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need substr_count function of SPL, reference: [function.substr-count.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
//Maximum numbers of emoticons
$iMaxEmoticons = 3;

//List of emoticons, each of them
$aEmoticonsList = array(
    ':)',
    ';)',
    ':>',
    ':(',
    //......
);

$sMessage = $_POST['androidMessage'];

$iEmoticonsCount = 0;
//Count each occurrence of emoticons
foreach ($aEmoticonsList as $sEmoticon) {
    //for utf8, use mb_substr_count instead
    $iEmoticonsCount += substr_count($sMessage, $sEmoticon);
}

//Check if maximum of emoticons is reached, print message and exit
if($iEmoticonsCount > $iMaxEmoticons){
    exit("Error max of ({$iMaxEmoticons}) emoticons reached, count {$iEmoticonsCount}.");
}
```

Comment: I am receiving data in utf8 format like "\uD83D\uDE1D" for one emoticon may be other also

Comment: Test again with mb_substr_count

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php)(For count the number of substring occurrences).

```
//Function to return array of check emoticons...
function emoticons() {
         $arrIcons = array(
                                        ':)',
                        ':-)',
                        ':D',
                        ':d',
                        ';)',
                        ':P',
                        ':-P',
                        ':-p',
                        ':p',
                        ':(',
                        ':o',
                        ':O',
                        ':0',
                        ':|',
                        ':-|',
                        ':/',
                        ':-/'
        );
        return $arrIcons;
}


//Check for emoticons...
$maxAllowIcon = 25;

$txtMYTEXTBOX = $_REQUEST['MYTEXTBOX'];//Get textbox inputed value...

$arrExistIcon = emoticons();//Get predefined icons...

//Check for how many emoticons used...
$cntEmoticons = 0;
foreach($arrExistIcon AS $keyImoticons => $emotIcons){
    $cntEmoticons += mb_substr_count($txtMYTEXTBOX, $emotIcons);    
}

//If icons more then maximum allowed then print message...
if($cntEmoticons > $maxAllowIcon){
    print('ERROR :: Maximum ' . $maxAllowIcon . ' emoticons allowed');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check it on android or server?

Comment: server side in php, I have edited the question..

Comment: @UmashankarSaw what  do  mean by emoticon? is it text
so your data format is a string containing alphabets and some numbers?